# ko commands Embedded in comment tags?

Tags: knockout.js, hottowel

I am trying to understand HotTowel more.

In ~/App/views/shell.html, it contains:

```
<header>
    <!--ko compose: {view: 'nav'} --><!--/ko-->
</header>
```

Are `ko` commands embedded within Html comment tags?  If so, what does the compose command do and how is the argument used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a feature of KnockoutJS and it's called "virtual elements". The main advantage is that you don't have to add additional HTML tags if it's unnecessary. It's very useful and it's very clean in some scenarios.
Mentioned in few places in Knockout documentation i.e.: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html and
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html

As of `compose` it's a custom binding and is explained in HotTowel README:

> The `compose` bindings for the header and footer are hard coded in Hot
>   Towel to point to the `nav` and `footer` views, respectively. The
>   compose binding for the section `#content` is bound to the `router`
>   module's active item. In other words, when you click a navigation link
>   its corresponding view is loaded in this area.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you point me to the HotTowel README?  I have been searching for something like this for some time.

Comment: README.md is the file displayed by github at main page of repo. Here's permalink, second paragraph of view section: https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel#shellhtml